# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect the GPU and I can't see 1920x1080 as a resolution after trying to install NVidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I have an NVidia 960M graphics card, and my laptop has a native reolution of 1920x1080. But `xrandr` shows a maximum resolution of 960x540 and

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

only shows

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

What can I do to get the maximum resolution as an option?

Answer (score 1):

To fix it I did this:

Use gtf to create a modeline

```
>>> gtf 1920 1080 60
# 1440x900 @ 59.90 Hz (GTF) hsync: 55.83 kHz; pclk: 106.29 MHz
  Modeline "1440x900_59.90"  106.29  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
```

Find your display name, mine was eDP-1, yours might be HDMI-1 if using a monitor

```
>>> xrandr --display
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
>>> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

>>> xrandr --addmode eDP-1 1920x1080_60.00
```